why does numpy complain about matplotlib install errors
I'm testing a python 3.7-32 installation using pip to install numpy.  During the clean install of python in an empty directory using
pip -install numpy-1.21.6-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl

I get the following errors:
ERROR: matplotlib 3.5.3 requires packaging>=20.0, which is not installed.
ERROR: matplotlib 3.5.3 requires pillow>=6.2.0, which is not installed.
ERROR: matplotlib 3.5.3 requires python-dateutil>=2.7, which is not installed.

But numpy doesn't even require matplotlib according to its metadata file.  What is causing these errors?

You probably have some packages installed before, which results in conflict. Have you created a new environment?

Perhaps a silly question, but why install numpy using a wheel? Does python -m pip install numpy (so that everything it needs gets installed automatically) not work?

to Zain:  I have installed a new environment in a new directory.  I also blew away the old Python 3.7 directory and removed Python from by %path% before  installing.
I didn't clean out the PIP cache though.

to Mike:  It isn't a silly question. I have customers we're giving sample python software.  I want to make sure they are using the versions we've tested.  Anything to avoid a tech-support call.
